# Ubuntu dual monitor set up - taskbars appear on other monitor

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to get my TV (connected via HDMI cable) to act as a second monitor to watch video etc. The TV is to my left, so in Display Preferences I unticked "Mirror Screens" and put the monitors like this:

```
            --------
----------  |  PC  |
|   TV   |  |      |
----------  --------
```

When I do this, the PC monitor comes up with just the desktop wallpaper and the interface - taskbar and windows, etc - moves to the TV screen. But if I swap the monitors around, the taskbars are still on the TV screen, with the windows (and desktop icons) on the PC screen.

Is there a way to set the computer monitor as the main one and the TV as the second screen?

PC: Dell Inspiron 531
Monitor: Samsung SyncMaster 720N
TV: Philips 26PFL5522D LCD TV

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually move the taskbars.  Right click on the bar and turn off expand, then you can drag it to the other screen.

Comment: +1. This is one of GNOME's more egregiously non-obvious features.